# Как узнать разорвано TCP соединение или нет?

Tags: android, tcp-ip

Есть сервер и андроид устройство в одной сети WI-FI. Андроид создает соединение(сокет) с сервером и отправляет данные. Как определить на андроид устройстве, если соединение по TCP прервано? Ведь андроид продолжит посылать инфу.

**UPADTE:** интересное наблюдение, что методы класса `Socket` `isClosed` и `isConnected` работают не так, как можно было бы подумать.
`isConnected` - если соединение было создано, метод будет всегда возвращать `true` 
`isClosed` - будет возвращаться `false`, только когда будет вызван метод `close()` со стороны клиента, а не сервера. Продолжаем поиски..

**UPDATE 2:** Нашёл интересный метод `checkError()` у `PrinterWriter`, который выдает `True`, если не получается передать сообщение по TCP соединению. Но здесь свои подводные камни: Если соединение разорвалось, андроид отправляет сообщение, в первый раз `checkError()` вернёт `false`, а true только уже в следующие разы(при условии, что соединение еще разорвано).

Comment: По таймауту. Есть ещё keepalive, но он не обязателен к использованию. Так что самый верный способ - таймаут.

Comment: @Sergey таймаут проверять следует в сёрвисе или можно при отправке сообщения на сервер ставить? Как вообще правильно реализовать проверку разрыва?

Comment: Проверять надо на стороне, где это особенно важно. На сервере само-собой не надо держать "зависшие" соединения. На клиенте, если он какой-то автономный тоже самое. Если приложение интерактивное (подразумевает общение с пользователем), то там наверно не обязательно. Даже самый глупый догадается перезагрузить если что.

Comment: у меня немного другая задача: есть сервер и клиент, они соединяются с помощью сокета. Клиент шлёт серверу сообщения, но вдруг сервер упал. Как клиенту узнать, что сервер упал? Ведь если клиент продолжит слать сообщения, он ничего не узнает..

Comment: Насчёт передачи даже не знаю. Надо сделать подтверждение получения. В самом TCP есть подтверждение пакетов, но не помню приводит ли нарушение этого протокола к ошибке на сокете в программе. По идее должно, он же не может слать вечно без подтверждения пакетов на другой стороне. Надо покурить мануалы.

Comment: @Sergey Вы имеете в виду подтверждение получения на самом сервере?

Comment: сделайте проверку, как в [WebSoket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), реализуйте свой ping\pong для обычного сокета или используйте `WebSoket`

Comment: @mit стоп, а разве если сервер обрубился, не должно вылетать исключение при попытке на него отправить сообщение? А за совет спасибо, сейчас попробуем